# How to integrate a binomial expression without expanding it before?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Let $(3-x^2)^3$ be a binomial expression. What is the integral of such expression?

First I tried integration by substitution, because there is a composition of two functions. But$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(3-x^2)=2x$ and I learned that this method only works if the integrand has the derivative of the inner function, multiplied by a constant.

Then I used what I learned about power series:

$$(3-x^2)^3=\binom{3}{0}3^3+\binom{3}{1}3^2(-x^2)+\binom{3}{2}3(-x^2)^2+\binom{3}{3}(-x^2)^3$$

And so,

\begin{align}
(3-x^2)^3&=27-27x^2+9x^4-x^6\\
\int(3-x^2)^3\,\mathrm dx&=\int(27-27x^2+9x^4-x^6) dx
\end{align}

Finally:

$$\displaystyle\int(3-x^2)^3dx=27x-9x^3+\frac{9}{5}x^5-\frac{1}{7}x^7+C$$

But imagine that the power is $10$, or maybe $20$? There is any way to integrate this kind of expression without expand it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a general way. However sometimes shortcuts can be made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us generalise a bit. The integral of $(a+bx^n)^m$ is given by (just expanding and integrating term-wise):

$$\int(a+bx^n)^m\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom m ka^{m-k}b^k\frac{x^{kn+1}}{kn+1}$$

Now I have not ever seen a nice form for a general expression like the sum on the right-hand side.

In fact, when I just look at it (for example when handed a similar sum in a different context), I usually think nothing except "Hey, that's the integral of $(a+bx^n)^m$".

For many usages of sums like the one on the right, the integral representation is actually a way of *simplifying* the problem; if there were nice closed forms currently (widely) known, the mathematical practice would probably *en masse* use those instead of the integral representation.

This all provides some circumstantial evidence to support the gut feeling that there probably is no general way.

Comment: I see. The integral of the expression is itself a series. For this particular kind of binomial, this particular kind of series is its integral.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to solve similar binomial integrals, called the Chebyshev method. It is based on substitution rules, in which 3 cases are given for the standard binomial expression y= x^m * (a + b*x^n)^p where m,n,p <>0 and rational numbers. 
Case 1) if p is a whole, non zero number and m and n fractions, then use the substiution u=x^s, where s is the lcd of the denominator of m and n
Case 2) if (m+1)/n is a whole number, then use the substitution
            u^s=(a + b*x^n), where s is the denominator of p
Case 3) if (m+1)/n +p is whole number, then use the substitution
            u^s=(ax^-n + b), where s is the denominator of p
if neither cases apply, the integral is not solvable via substitution.

Comment: Consider [using MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.